# Why does the execution of this basic program gives an error?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I don't really understand, why does the execution of this program give an error?

```
  int main()
  {
        char *b;
        *b='2';
        printf("%c",*b);
        return 0;
  }
```

Comment: The [basic] tag is for the BASIC programming language(s). This looks like C, or maybe C++, so I changed the tag.

Comment: For future reference, please tell us exactly what error you see, preferably by copy-and-pasting the error message into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, `b` is uninitialized and thus may point to any arbitrary location. When you say `*b =...`, you are trying to write to some unspecified location, which (depending on what that location is) often causes an error (say a segfault). Perhaps you meant to declare `b` as a `char` instead of a pointer to one?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like its taken straight from homework or a textbook. When you declare the char pointer b, it is not given a memory address (where it points to) by default, it just contains whatever was in the memory location beforehand. This means that if you attempt to work with the value (*b = '2' or printf) it will try to read this random information left over in memory as an address and look for a char at that address. This would cause a segmentation fault or if you're unlucky, it would grab garbage from the memory and use it as a char value.

The solution would be to create a char variable (char a) and set the pointer to the location of a (b = &a).

Hopefully this helps, and good luck on your studies.